# How to host duplex wcf service on a VPS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, vps

i am trying to host a wcf service which has a following attribute;

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

and i am creating host class like this;

```
    var uri = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:7951");
    var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ChatService), uri);
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    if (smb == null) host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior());
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "mex");
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IChat), new NetTcpBinding(), "");
    host.Open();
```

So, on developer computer and dedicated server this is working. However, what i need to do is, host this on a VPS (vitual private server).

I thought making a web project and adding this code block to global.asax application start method. but this failed. I suspect problem that the port is closed from firewall maybe.

What solution should I follow?

Comment: did u find any solution to it. I am doing same on VPS, is it successful ?

Comment: @Marshal Sorry, but no...

Comment: I am working successfully on it now..let me know if you are facing any problems with your service

Comment: @Marshal I have postpones this project but I will appriciate if you post a brief explanation of your approach.